# SAS. Create a field if not exist

Tags: sas

I'm very noob in SAS.

I want to check if a value exist based on a date.

Example. I have a table with dates 1may to 3may and a variable called y. I want to check if `y="hi"` in every day. If it doesn´t exist, I want to create the field.

input

```
| date | y |
|:-----|:--|
|1may  |la |
|1may  |le |
|1may  |hi |
|2may  |la |
|2may  |le |
|3may  |la |
|3may  |le |
|3may  |hi |
```

output

```
| date | y |
|:-----|:--|
|1may  | la|
|1may  | le|
|1may  |hi |
|2may  |la |
|2may  |le |
|2may  |hi |
|3may  |la |
|3may  |le |
|3may  |hi |
```

Sorry for my english.
Thank you

Comment: You are not adding any in new VARIABLES in your output compared to your input. It looks like you want to insert an OBSERVATION not create a new "field".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to add an observation, not make any new variable (aka FIELD).

One way to do this is to make a dataset with one observation per DATE and with 'hi' as the value of Y and then combine that with the existing dataset.

So if you input dataset is named HAVE and it is already sorted by DATE and Y your code could be.

```
data all_dates;
   set have ;
   by date ;
   if first.date ;
   y= 'hi';
   keep date y;
end;

data want ;
  merge all_dates have ;
  by date y ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the result of a logical evaluation to a variable.  An evaluation will return `0` for false and `1` for true.

Example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  hi_flag = (y='hi');  * new variable hi_flag contains result of test (y='hi');
run;
```